# selected option in the one multiple select box has to push on the other multiple select box and vice-versa using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having 2 multiple select boxes like these.([image: click here][image: result image])

By using Agular2 it is not push or pop any element can anyone please help me to resolve the issue and perfect coding for these functionality using Angular2?

Thank you! Examples programming make the most sense.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/grlQ1VSsG3rnTrczJxv0?p=preview my plkr code

Comment: here the code in plukr @Omasu Plus